# WP_Query Excluding pages with Order is 0

Tags: wp-query, exclude, menu-order

I have a custom WP_Query with the following arguments

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'tile-home',
    'meta_value' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

That selects all the published pages which have the custom field **tile-home** set to **1** and orders them by the page attribute **Order**.

How can I edit the arguments in order (please, forgive me the pun) to exclude all the pages that have menu_order set to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define custom `where` like this if your table is `wp_posts`

```
function _20170112( $where ){    

  $where = $where . ' AND wp_posts.menu_order > 0 ';             
  return $where;
}
```

And sandwich your query with this:

```
$args = array(      
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'tile-home',
    'meta_value' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);


add_filter( 'posts_where', '_20170112' );
$q = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter( 'posts_where', '_20170112' );
```

Comment: I believe your filter needs to take the table prefix into account like this;

    `function foo( $where ) {
        global $wpdb;
 return $where . " AND $wpdb->posts.menu_order > 0 ";
    }`